# Show all comments from a specific user in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to consolidate all the comments, on various products, from the logged in user in an "Account" page.

My initial plan was to request all comments from the user id.

Because I created a Profile model, I thought the right way to approach this was to link it to the profile id, and not directly to the use id.

Obviously, it's not working.

Am I close to it? or should I think of it completely differently? (new to programming, as you can see on the code)

**Starting with my models.py**

```
class ReviewRating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product,related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    review=models.TextField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s - %s'%(self.user, self.product, self.date_added)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    general_reviews = models.ForeignKey(ReviewRating,null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

def **str**(self):
return str(self.user)

**Views.py**

```
def account(response, profile_id):
    generalreviews_list = Profile.general_reviews.objects.all(pk=profile_id)
    return render(response,"main/account.html", {'generalreviews_list':generalreviews_list})
```

**URLS**

```
path("account/<profile_id>/", views.account, name="account"),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to link it with the main user model in your case it will be best to link it with user_id. After that, you can use the following query to access all the comments made by the currently logged-in user.

Views.py

```
current_user = request.user
queryset_obj = Model.objects.filter(foreign_key_field_name=current_user)
context = {
   'comments' = quesyset_obj,
}
```

Templates.py

```
{% for comment in comments %}
   {{comment.review}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: HI Usama, I think you went a bit too fast for me here. From the first setcion of your message, I uderstand that I need to change references from profile_id to user_id (for views and url). Am I right to think the bit of code you wrote down is to go in the views.py? Finally regarding the queryset_obj line should look like this: queryset_obj = ReviewRating.objects.filter(User=current_user). Sorry for my confused question, I am likely to have more as soon as you reply :)

Comment: Hi Phil, Yes you are exactly right. This code needs to go in the views.py file. Sorry for the model name issue, I forgot you mentioned your model name in the question. After this code, you can pass queryset_obj to the front-end and loop through it for getting all the comments.

Comment: Still working on it! Something is wrong in my code somewhere, will try to fix it and come back to you! (thanks for sticking around!)

Answer (score 2):

**Method - 1** (easiest and logical method)

profile.html:

```
{% for comment in request.user.reviewrating_set.all %}
    {{ comment.review }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Method - 2** (by setting a related_name what Django already defines one called foo_set )

You need to add a related_name  attribute to the user field under `ReviewRating`

```
class ReviewRating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comments")
```

### That's It! You can use it on the profile HTML like this:

profile.html:

```
{% for comment in request.user.comments %}
    {{ comment.review }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I am missing something. When you put "comment" in the template, do you mean "ReviewRating"? And do I keep all the rest of the code? I tried with the existing code, and also by removing all references to "user/profile_id", but no result. Any pointers?

Comment: You don’t *need* to set a related name, Django automatically creates one with .modelname_set - eg .reviewrating_set

Comment: @0sVoid,  I just learned that from you. I always used to set a related name for this usage. Thanks!

Comment: @PhilM, If you share your profile.html I try to help you. I was just showed up the logic.